# Handling errors in HTTP requests

Tags: haskell

I am trying to retrieve the values of a few HTTP headers. Since I do not need the body, I am using `httpNoBody` as follows.

```
import Network.HTTP.Simple

-- | Load page and return HTTP response headers.
fetchHeaders :: String -> IO (Response ())
fetchHeaders = httpNoBody <=< parseRequest

-- | Retrieve the HTTP header 'Age' from the response.
getAge url = getResponseHeader Header.hAge <$> fetchHeaders url
```

1. I am unable to drop the explicit parameter from `getAge`. Why?
2. If the required HTTP header is not there in the response, I get an empty list (as expected). If the fetch itself failed for some reason, I am getting an exception. How do I make sure that even in that case I return an empty list?

```
ghci> getResponseHeader Header.hAge <$> fetchHeaders "https://stackoverflow.com"
[]

ghci> getResponseHeader Header.hAge <$> fetchHeaders "https://stackoverflow.coms"
*** Exception: HttpExceptionRequest Request {
  host                 = "stackoverflow.coms"
  port                 = 443
  secure               = True
  requestHeaders       = []
  path                 = "/"
  queryString          = ""
  method               = "GET"
  proxy                = Nothing
  rawBody              = False
  redirectCount        = 10
  responseTimeout      = ResponseTimeoutDefault
  requestVersion       = HTTP/1.1
  proxySecureMode      = ProxySecureWithConnect
}
 (ConnectionFailure Network.Socket.getAddrInfo (called with preferred socket type/protocol: AddrInfo {addrFlags = [AI_ADDRCONFIG], addrFamily = AF_UNSPEC, addrSocketType = Stream, addrProtocol = 0, addrAddress = 0.0.0.0:0, addrCanonName = Nothing}, host name: Just "stackoverflow.coms", service name: Just "443"): does not exist (nodename nor servname provided, or not known))
```